# Ubuntu Always On Top Over Fullscreen

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ubuntu, window, ubuntu-14.04

I am running into a problem setting up some automation on Ubuntu and was hoping for some help. I need to be able to start chrome, set full screen, start another window, set that to always on top, and then set focus back to chrome. This should end up with a small window on top of chrome, but chrome receiving all user inputs.

I've done a lot of digging and the best I can come up with is using wmctrl:

```
// Set chrome as fullscreen<br/>
wmctrl -r [ChromeWindowTitle] -b add,fullscreen

// Set the app as always on top<br/>
wmctrl -r [AppWindowTitle] -b add,above

// Activate chrome<br/>
xdotool search --name [ChromeWindowTitle] | awk '{ system("xdotool windowactivate --sync " $1) }'
```

The always on top and full screen work, but when an app is in full screen mode it seems to supersede the always on top stack. I've been able to verify this through a bunch of experiments. Basically what I have been able to verify is:

1) I can force an app full screen
2) I can force an app always on top
3) I cannot do both and have the always on top app on top of the full screen app. The full screen app is always displayed on top.

So the question is, is it possible (and how is it possible) to have a window floating over a full screen window? I'm running a fairly vanilla Ubuntu 14.04 so there shouldn't be any big surprises there.

Thanks in advance.
-Mike

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?